# Does God create some people Heterosexual and others Homosexual?

Tags: sin, sexuality, nature-of-man

It is quite common for people who identify themselves as homosexual to say that God created them this way. Some way even go so far as to say it was a misfortune that they were born into:

> "Unfortunately for me, God made me gay."

This line of reasoning usually continues with 
- "so I can't do anything about it"
- "it's not my fault, it's God's fault that I sin"

Others claim that since they were created that way it must not be a sin.

What does Christianity hold about the way people were created? Does having something in our natures make it not a sin?

Comment: What I'm curious about is why people choose to maintain this assault on sexual preference and abandon so much of the OT where by the same citing of excerpts we can determine that something like being a victim of rape justifies punishment by death. Didn't Jesus give the commandment to love one another? I get it. Bible says men who lay with other men suck. Maybe conveniently omitted is the context in which this happens. If they love each other, why is that the same as hedonistic orgies?  http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/RationalWiki:Annotated_Bible/Deuteronomy#Deuteronomy_22:23-27

Comment: I'm wondering if this should be locked this as well.  It's going to continue to draw comments and debate, which isn't really the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Richard It would help if SE staff wouldn't set a bad example by miss-using the comment feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As [homosexuality](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/381/why-do-some-christians-believe-it-is-moral-to-be-a-homosexual) is a [sin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/121/what-does-the-bible-say-about-homosexuality), it is safe to conclude that God did not "create them this way". Just like God didn't create thieves as such, murderers as such, liars as such, etc.

It is as a byproduct of the fallen world in which we live that [Romans 1:26-27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:26-27&version=NASB) was written:

> For this reason God gave them over to degrading passions; for their women exchanged the natural function for that which is unnatural, and in the same way also the men abandoned the natural function of the woman and burned in their desire toward one another, men with men committing indecent acts and receiving in their own persons the due penalty of their error.

Whether there are genetic mutations (errors resulting from Adam's first sin) that *contribute* to some people's homosexual tendencies may be debated. But as to it being God's purpose, intent, or design? No - He did not create them that way.

[Genesis 1:26-27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%201&version=NASB) also indicates that it is not God's intent:

> Then God said, "Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our likeness; and let them rule over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the sky and over the cattle and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creeps on the earth." God created man in His own image, in the image of God He created him; male and female He created them.

Comment: I think this is a good answer that for some reason got burried at the bottom. However I think it could be improved with a note about what Christian traditions this view speaks for and which it does not (there are a couple, and a few on the fence but it should be easy to categorize them). As a question about Christianity, this speaks for a majority but it would paint a more useful picture of Christianity (not just correct doctrine) if it was identified.

Comment: @Caleb - I'm not sure which traditions would disagree ... for example, some baptist churches teach now that homosexuality is *not* a sin, whereas most teach that it *is*.

Comment: Any teaching that is different from Gods word is not Gods word. [2 Timothy 4:3](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/2-timothy/4/#v55004003)> "For there will be a period of time when they will not put up with the wholesome teaching, but according to their own desires, they will surround themselves with teachers to have their ears tickled."

Comment: How does this reconcile with [Romans 9?](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+9&version=NIV) Some pots are for destruction and others for glory. He made them all the way they are. Also, what about [Psalm 139:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+139), which indicates a very intimate touch with each person's creation? Whether homosexuals are "born that way" or not is somewhat irrelevant. Almost all think they are and that's the best we have right now.

Comment: @fredsbend - I don't think your statement "[a]lmost all think they are" is not very accurate.

Comment: @warren Let me clarify. Almost all homosexuals think they are "born that way." Again and again that is what is reported. People acting out with homosexual behavior because of an emotional or abusive incident(s) is not necessarily the same thing. That is more similar to promiscuity ("the girl with daddy issues").

Comment: @fredsbend perhaps your experience / reading has lead in a different direction, but I haven't heard that as a widespread claim in several years

Comment: @warren Depends on what you are reading. If you get most of your info from sex addict recovery stuff, then yes, you are going to see more of what you are saying. If you take a look at the random sample polls you probably will not. Though, I concede that, for the afflicted, it is difficult to see how a traumatizing event has affected your behavior.

Comment: @fredsbend "for the afflicted, it is difficult to see how a traumatizing event has affected your behavior." Perhaps if they (and yourself) were to see the percentage breakdown of how many paedophiles were abused as children it might lead them (you) to revise this opinion.

Answer (score 15):

*<sup>This answer is based on the doctrine of original sin as held by at least Lutheranism. Related question: [Are we born sinners?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/are-we-born-sinners)</sup>*

There are, in fact, **two important questions** here.  One explicit, one implicit.

### The explicit question

***Does God create some people heterosexual and others homosexual?***

As other answerers have meritoriously pointed out, the Bible depicts homosexual acts as an abomination.

> [**Romans 1:26-27 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:26-27&version=ESV)
> For this reason God gave them up to dishonorable passions. For their women exchanged natural relations for those that are contrary to nature; and the men likewise gave up natural relations with women and were consumed with passion for one another, men committing shameless acts with men and receiving in themselves the due penalty for their error.
>
> **[1 Corinthians 6:9 (ESV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%206:9&version=ESV)**
> Or do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived: neither the sexually immoral, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor men who practice homosexuality,
>
> [**Leviticus 18:22 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2018:22&version=ESV)
> You shall not lie with a male as with a woman; it is an abomination.

Remember what God said when he looked at the creation, after creating man:

> **[Genesis 1:31 (ESV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%201:31&version=ESV)**
> And God saw everything that he had made, and behold, it was very good. And there was evening and there was morning, the sixth day.

No, I don't believe God created anyone homosexual, triggered to do what he sees as an abomination. *But do read on...*

### The implicit question

***Are some people born heterosexual and others homosexual?***

How God created us and how we were born are two entirely separate matters. God created us perfect, but in the Fall of Man, Adam and Eve chose sin and the entire humankind after that is born with original sin.

> [**Psalm 51:5 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalms%2051:5&version=ESV)
> Behold, I was brought forth in iniquity,
> and in sin did my mother conceive me.

**We are born sinners**, even though God did not create us such.

I don't know how this actually works. It might be that all of us are born perverted in some way: one prone to murder, one to lie, one to steal, one to be proud, one to have extramarital sex, one to have homosexual sex. Being born in such a way wouldn't make the action right, though more understandable.

Praise the Lord for carrying the burden of our sins, for we are indeed full of sin!

### Conclusion

God did not create any of us sinners, yet we all are.

Some of us might be born homosexual. The Bible doesn't clearly state either way, and we're [still waiting for conclusive scientific research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biology_and_sexual_orientation).

Comment: while I think the word "perverted" is out of place there (a bit unhelpful as a word), I find it odd that many Christians are **so** fixated on just one item out of your list, but not so much about the others.

Comment: *and we're still waiting for conclusive scientific research.* And science may or may not be able to to prove it.

Comment: @FMS Science will be able to prove it (whichever way it ends up being), though only after science is able to deduce psychology as a whole (i.e. examining brain structure and thought patterns, etc. - things science cannot *yet* do without uncertainty).

Comment: @Qix *'Science will be able to prove it'* - May we hold you to your prediction?

Comment: @FMS Please do. :)

Comment: @Qix Please see my answer below. From scripture I deduced that evil spirits are involved in the infection. This may be beyond what science can measure.

Comment: @FMS Science doesn't deal with the notion of spirits, god, or religion at all, so that's an incorrect assessment.

Comment: @Qix *'Science doesn't deal with the notion of spirits, god, or religion at all.'* - My point.

Comment: @FMS So then if science were to find an answer, would it then prove that homosexuality is indeed unrelated to evil spirits and the *"infection"*, as you call it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19101/discussion-between-fms-and-qix).

Answer (score 14):

It's important to examine the basic premise: does "sexual orientation" actually exist in the first place?  The concept has become ingrained enough in our culture that we take it for granted, but when you look at history, that wasn't always the case.

What you see in ancient cultures is many different attitudes towards sexuality, and patterns of sexual behavior that strongly reflect their culture's beliefs about what's acceptable.  In ancient Rome, where a young boy was considered the sexual ideal, it was common for both men and women of means to take a much younger male lover.  (Younger female lovers, not so much.  It wasn't part of their culture.)  In cultures where women hold the bulk of political and economic power, female/female pairings, particularly involving a younger woman seeking the economic security a wealthy older woman can provide, were far more common than modern statistics on homosexuality would suggest you should see.

It's not very politically correct, but historical evidence strongly suggests that there's no such thing as sexual orientation, only sexual *behavior* and society's attitudes towards it.  So no, God does not create some people as homosexuals and others as heterosexuals.

Answer (score 12):

I think that since God finds homosexuality detestable, it would be safe to assume that God does not create people in a manner that he finds detestable.

We see in [Leviticus 20:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2020:13%20&version=NIV) that he finds it detestable:

> 13 “‘If a man has sexual relations with a man as one does with a
>   woman, both of them have done what is detestable. They are to be put
>   to death; their blood will be on their own heads.

In the New Testament, there is [Romans 1:26-27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%201:26-27&version=NIV)

> 26 Because of this, God gave them over to shameful lusts. Even their
>   women exchanged natural sexual relations for unnatural ones. 27 In the
>   same way the men also abandoned natural relations with women and were
>   inflamed with lust for one another. Men committed shameful acts with
>   other men, and received in themselves the due penalty for their error.

With those two in mind, I think it's safe to say that God would not create something that he finds "detestable".

Supporting this is this:

[1 John 1:5 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=%201%20John%201%3a%205&version=NIV)

> This is the message we have heard from him and declare to you: God is light; in him there is no darkness at all.

Since there is no darkness or evil in God at all, he cannot create evil--he does not create that which is detestable to him.

Furthermore, (as warren pointed out), we are made in God's image ([Genesis 1:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%201:26&version=NIV)).  Since there is no darkness in God, it can be clear that we, created in His image, were not created with darkness in us.  God did not create us this way.

Therefore, no.  *Per the bible*, God did not create some people as homosexual.

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing your input on this question: [Are some people created to go to hell?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/217/are-some-people-created-to-go-to-hell/) - as your viewpoint that God does not make people in a manner he finds detestable is the opposite of the highest voted answer in that thread

Comment: `God would not create something that he finds "detestable".` He created man which is the most detestable thing on Earth.

Comment: When he created man, we were not detestable, but sinless and perfect.  It was man's choice in the Garden of Eden that made us detestable.

Comment: @Richard, if we were perfect there, why did we choose to sin?

Comment: @beetstra  That is a fabulous question!  However, this is not the place for such a large answer.  Instead, I'm going to steal your thunder and post that as a question myself!  Here it is: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1378/if-adam-and-eve-were-perfect-why-did-they-choose-to-sin

Comment: "I think that since God finds homosexuality detestable, it would be safe to assume that God does not create people in a manner that he finds detestable." God also finds mutilating your body detestable, yet some are born so deformed you could not tell the difference.

Comment: This argument doesn't make any sense. If people are born homosexual, and God creates people, then God creates homosexuals. He might be testing them, for example.

Comment: Do not confuse sexuality with gender or femininity/masculinity.  Sexuality is your preference for whom you have sex.  Children are not born with the desire to have sex.  Therefore they are not born with a sexuality.  Although, they may be born with personality traits that are generally associated with homosexuality.  But personality traits and sexuality are not the same.

Comment: I am not taking a position on the origin of homosexuality. I am saying your statement "I think that since God finds homosexuality detestable, it would be safe to assume that God does not create people in a manner that he finds detestable." is not a logical argument, because God could be creating homosexual people and expecting them not to sin for some purpose we don't know. The Bible does not say that God does not like people with homosexual desires, it only takes a position on the act of homosexuality, does it not?

Comment: That's a well thought out stance. But it still presumes that people are born homosexual. *"...because God could be creating homosexual people and expecting them not to sin..."* That may be, but it [begs the question](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/begquest.html) of the origin of homosexuality. With that said, the first sentence of this answer also begs the question. However, dropping that first sentence, the answer stands on its own. Still, all of this *debate* is really surrounding the origin of homosexuality. Romans 1:26-27 implies that this is not something at birth, but due to the will of man

Comment: Well, I read it as implying that *choosing not to abstain* is the problem. That again does not imply anything on the origin of homosexuality (of, if anything, it says that it is God who gave them [homosexual] lust). By saying that some people are by nature homosexual, one only implies that they are only attracted by people of the same gender, not that they *must* commit sins.

Answer (score 0):

> One of you will say to me: “Then why does God still blame us? For who resists his will?” But who are you, O man, to talk back to God? “Shall what is formed say to him who formed it, ‘Why did you make me like this?’” Does not the potter have the right to make out of the same lump of clay some pottery for noble purposes and some for common use? What if God, choosing to show his wrath and make his power known, bore with great patience the objects of his wrath—prepared for destruction? What if he did this to make the riches of his glory known to the objects of his mercy, whom he prepared in advance for glory — even us, whom he also called, not only from the Jews but also from the Gentiles? -- Romans 9:19-24 (NIV)

This goes quite hand-in-hand with "[Are some people created to go to Hell?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/217/105)", a question over which there is quite a bit of debate.

Rather than choosing to "blame God" for it though, let's look simply at the facts. The simple fact is that Paul said it was better not to marry at all (1 Corinthians 7:6-7, 38). What he says here is to go against your human nature, and follow God with your whole heart, regardless of your desires. He also concedes that if you cannot refrain from sexual immorality, that you should marry.

There are two aspects of the homosexuality issue that have to be addressed in order to fully answer "Does God make some people homosexual?" The first issue that I would like to address is the mental aspect (psychological). I have quite a few homosexual friends and family members. In every case, each of these individuals has deep-rooted issues with their parents for one reason or another, rooted very specifically in the physical and emotional.

There are loads of different things ranging from watching others be abused, being abused themselves (not necessarily sexually), or just an absolutely terrible relationship or complete lack of a loving relationship with a parent or parents. I have confirmed this theory in at least seven of my homosexual friends. Did God cause each of these confirmed circumstances that led to homosexual desires? Once again debatable, but the first fact here is that the homosexual tendency stems not from nature, but rather from nurture. It's an inability to cope with previous emotional distress brought on by parents and role models.

The second aspect of homosexuality is the spiritual aspect. God's command was to be fruitful and multiply, and homosexual relationships are incapable of producing offspring. The human body is not designed for homosexual relationships physically. Thanks to a sin nature brought on by Adam's sin, we have desires that are outside of the scope that God created us for.

There are lots of things that we do that are harmful or just "aren't good" things to do, yet our sin nature leads to do those things, even to the point of our own destruction. One could just as easily say "God made me an alcoholic." but the simple fact is the alcoholic wasn't born with a bottle in his mouth. Nor was the smoker born with a cigarette in his mouth. We all have strong desires that result from our sin nature that we have a *choice* to either give in to or resist. As an example of this, I have a homosexual friend who after years of homosexuality came to Christ. He openly admits to still having those desires. However, he resists them, avoids situations that could lead to temptation, and does his best to live for God.

It's no easier or harder for a homosexual to live for God than anyone else with a sin nature (all of us). We simply cannot give place to the Devil and blame God for our actions. In reality, does it *matter* if God made you with homosexual desires? Does it *matter* if God made you with the tendency to become an alcoholic? I posit that the only thing that matters is that you resist that temptation.

Comment: This is just describing homosexuals as basically "people with issues". Ask around better, the only issues homosexuals have is with people blaming them for what they feel. Your anecdotal experience does not prove anything, besides the fact that you have convinced yourself of something...

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm bringing back an old post, but I think this question should have this scripture in it. God did not create us to be homosexual. That is why the first humans where man and women.

If God created man and women, then gave a very straightforward commandment against homosexuality, do you think he would make within people that desire? By making that law, God shows that he never intended us to do such things.

Here are a couple scriptures to support this:

[**Numbers 23:19**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/numbers/23/#v4023019)

> *"God is not a mere man who tells lies,
>   Nor a son of man who changes his mind.
>   When he says something, will he not do it
>   When he speaks, will he not carry it out?"*

[**James 1:13**](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/james/1/#v59001013):

> "When under trial, let no one say: “I am being tried by God.” For with evil things God cannot be tried, nor does he himself try anyone."

Answer (score -2):

Breifly, to answer questions posed.

God created me this way. No. No one is created gay.

It was misfortune that they were born into:  We are all born in corruption.

Unfortunately God made me gay. No. God did not make you gay.

I can't do anything about it. Yes. You may receive a new birth.

Its God's fault that I sin.  No. One makes a choice to sin.

Since they were created that way,it must not be a sin.  It is a sin because it transgresses the law.

What does Christianity hold about the way people are created?  I would like to believe that they hold to the bible account. However, honestly, I have no idea

Does having something in our nature make it not a sin?  No.  A sin is a sin, until such time that the law is changed, it  remains a sin.

How were we created?  All scripture taken from KJV

Genesis 1;27
So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.

Genesis 2;7
And the Lord God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrills the breath of life; and man became a living soul.

Genesis 2;22
And the rib, which the Lord God had taken from man, made he a woman, and brought her unto the man.

Genesis 1;31
And God saw every thing that he had made, and behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day.

I believe that the creation as God said, was very good.

The Fall
Genesis 3;13
And the Lord God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.

Genesis 3;15
And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.

Genesis 3;16
Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee.

Genesis 3;19
In the sweat of thy face shalt thou eat bread, till thou return unto the ground; for out of it wast thou taken: for dust thou art, and unto dust shalt thou return.

We have three involved in the fall, Adam, Eve, and the serpent.

The family after the fall is corrupt, it no longer is pure, but now has the taint of sin.

Genesis 4;1,2
And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and said, I have gotten a man from the Lord. 2 And she again bare his brother Abel. And Abel was a keeper of the sheep, but Cain was a tiller of the ground

Hebrews 11;4
By faith Abel offered unto God a more excellent sacrifice than Cain, by which he obtained  witness that he was righteous, God testifying of his gifts: and being dead yet speaketh.

I John 3;12
Not as Cain, who was of that wicked one, and slew his brother. And wherefore slew he him? Because his own works were evil, and his brother's righteous.

The two offspring of Adam and Eve, represent good(righteous), and evil(unrighteous).  One is not corrupt, and one is corrupt.

The Heart. We are guided by the characteristics of our heart.

Jeremiah 17;9,10
The heart is deceitful above all things, who can know it. 10 I the Lord search the heart, I try the reins, even to give every man according to his ways,nd according to his doings.

As long as the heart remains tainted, we are all susceptible to the wickedness therein.

Romans Chapter 1, verses 18-32 provides some description of homosexual acts as well as other perversions. Leviticus Chapter 18 speaks of homosexuality and other sexual sins. Satan has had great success in infiltrating the world with evil. As noted in the bible, good is being called evil and evil is being called good. The truth of homosexuality is not happiness as promoted, but eternal death

Ephesians 2;10
For we are his worhmanship, created in Christ Jesus unto good works, which God hath ordained that we should walk in them.

Romans 7;18,19
For I know that in me (that is, in my flesh,) dwelleth no good thing: for to will is present with me; but how to perform that which is good I find not. 19 For the good that I would, I do not: but the evil which I would not, that I do.

Believers are a product of the Holy Spirit, unbelievers remain tainted.

Matthew 7;17,18

Even so every good tree bringeth forth good fruit: but a corrupt tree bringeth forth evil fruit. 18 A good tree cannot bring forth evil fruit, neither can a corrupt tree bring forth good fruit.

Comment: *No one is created gay.* The irrefutable evidence?

Comment: "God created me this way. No. No one is created gay." -- I don't know if God creates people with specific gender orientations, however it is factually incorrect to say that people are not created gay. People may as well be born that way, certainly they claim not to be able to choose whom they like.