# What did Pope Francis mean when he said "who am I to judge" homosexuals?

Tags: catholicism, homosexuality, pope-francis, judging-others

It's approaching two years since this happened, but it seems relevant in light of recent events concerning homosexuality.

Speaking to reporters on his plane who had asked him about a "gay lobby" in the Vatican, Francis said, "[If someone is gay and he searches for the Lord and has good will, who am I to judge?](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/30/world/europe/pope-francis-gay-priests.html)"

Clearly the *church* judges their actions (whenever there *are* actions accompanying the desires). What exactly did he mean by "who am I to judge"?

Comment: I thought this had already been asked, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @freshened [Probably here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88300/catholic-culture-ministry-and-apologetics/88312#88312)

Comment: @fredsbend Please change your name to freshened. Just for a month?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude lol. Or maybe freshend. I might.

Comment: It has already been asked, because I'm sure I answered it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I searched a lot before asking, as did Fredsbend (it appears). You may be thinking of a different "What did Francis mean by ______?" question (like [this one](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/19024/9289); there have been quite a few. If this _has_ been asked before, then apparently it's hard to find and this one will be a good sign-post for it.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I know I've answered this question, but I can't find it in my answers in my profile. I think the question was deleted. Presumably my answer wasn't upvoted :-( Feel free to flag this comment for moderator attention; mods can search deleted things.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think you are correct. FMS asked it. I don't recall exactly the problems with it, but it was downvoted a good deal.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I looked through your deleted answers and the only one I could find that got close was [your answer to "How did Adam and Eve sin when they lacked a sinful nature?"](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25442/how-did-adam-and-eve-sin-when-they-lacked-a-sinful-nature/25446?s=4|1.0000#25446). Perhaps the answer you're thinking of isn't deleted. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @fredsbend: FMS had 4 deleted ([1](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33934/58), [2](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33935/58), [3](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33918/58), [4](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33921/58)) and 3 undeleted questions ([1](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35253/58), [2](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33937/58), [3](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33773/58)) about homosexuality/gay marriage and Scripture/Catholicism. None of them had an answer or comment from AndrewLeach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pope Francis means that those with same-sex attraction who refuse to act on their impulses for the sake of the Kingdom should not be judged. Those with heterosexual attraction often judge a homosexual attracted person based on his or her feelings he/she cannot control, even if the person doesn't act on them. Pope Francis is saying that we shouldn't condemn same-sex attraction, as it is not something a person can control. I would go so far as to say that Pope Francis implicitly means that we should show mercy and compassion to those who, through weakness, fell into the trap of acting on homosexual feelings.

What Pope Francis is NOT saying is that homosexuality as in the lifestyle, and in particular sodomy, should be condoned. He's also not saying that homosexual feelings are good; a person who has such feelings cannot sin for have such feelings, because they are out of his control, but the feelings are still a temptation and "disorder." People often get annoyed by the Church's use of "disordered," but most don't realize that, to the Church, a heterosexual sexual feeling aimed at someone who is not your spouse is disordered as well, but neither homosexual attraction or adultuous feelings are a sin in themselves unless a person entertain them and act on them (through sodomy or adultery respectively).

Basically, Pope Francis has in mind the ancient distinction between the will and the passions/emotions: we have free will, but our passions or emotions (which we have in common with other animals) are not entirely up to our control, due to our fallen nature (this war between the reason and the passions over the will is called concupiscience). As such, Pope Francis distingishes between homosexual actions (controlled by the will) and homosexual feelings (controlled by the passions), and points out that homosexual feelings alone cannot be a sin, period, and that a person who suffers from them cannot be blamed or thought of as "lesser" because he possesses the temptation: we all have our temptations.

Most importantly, we should pray that all who suffer from sexual temptations, whether they be hetersexual or homosexual, emerge victoriously over their temptations in the Kingdom of God.

Christi pax.

Comment: How do you know this is what he really meant? You don't cite anything.

Comment: @ Geremia: I'm interpreting his comments with the idea that the Pope is Catholic, that his words are compatible with previous teaching. For example, the Catechism of the Catholic Church teaches us that homosexuals, like all persons, are to be loved, and it is precisely because we love them that we condemn homosexual behavior.

Comment: The pope is the false prophet of Revelation 13, he dresses like a lamb(in white) but speaks like a dragon(his speech is full of God opposing doctrine) like ecumenism and all.