# What is the biblical basis that people who are attracted to the same sex were not created by God that way?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-man, homosexuality

cf. [Does God create some people Heterosexual and others Homosexual? [closed]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/does-god-create-some-people-heterosexual-and-others-homosexual)

> It is quite common for people who identify themselves as homosexual to
>   say that God created them this way. Some way even go so far as to say
>   it was a misfortune that they were born into:
>
> > "Unfortunately for me, God made me gay."
>
> This line of reasoning usually continues with 
>   - "so I can't do anything about it"
>   - "it's not my fault, it's God's fault that I sin"
>
> Others claim that since they were created that way it must not be a
>   sin.
>
> What does Christianity hold about the way people were created? Does
>   having something in our natures make it not a sin?

The question here is what is the biblical basis that God does NOT create homosexual people as homosexuals (i.e those who say that since they were born that way, God must have created them that way, what is the biblical basis that God has not created [/and does not create] those people that way)?

---

**Note:**

*[I take people at their word when they say they were born that way and see no reason to discount their testimony and that of their parents until some other refuting evidence becomes available.]*

Comment: This question is not quite clear enough - putting 'some' in the question makes it too indistinct. Are you trying to ask *what is the biblical basis for the belief that people who are attracted to the same sex were not created by God that way?*

Comment: @curiousdannii Except for the *'belief'* part, it may be asked that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question here is what is the biblical basis that God does NOT create homosexual people as homosexuals.

It is understandable that homosexuals might feel they were created that way because the Bible says that they are under a compulsion that is a result of a judicial act of God. They misunderstand this compulsion as something that they were born with as opposed to something which was given them as punishment.

> **Romans 1:20-22**
>   For the invisible things of him from the creation of
>   the world are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are
>   made, even his eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without
>   excuse:   Because that, when they knew God, they glorified him not as
>   God, neither were thankful; but became vain in their imaginations, and
>   their foolish heart was darkened.   Professing themselves to be wise,
>   they became fools,
>
> **Romans 1:26-27**
>     For this cause God gave them up unto vile affections:
>   for even their women did change the natural use into that which is
>   against nature:   And likewise also the men, leaving the natural use
>   of the woman, burned in their lust one toward another; men with men
>   working that which is unseemly, and receiving in themselves that
>   recompence of their error which was meet.
>
> **Romans 1:28-31**  
> And even as they did not like to retain God in their
>   knowledge, God gave them over to a reprobate mind, to do those things
>   which are not convenient;   Being filled with all unrighteousness,
>   fornication, wickedness, covetousness, maliciousness; full of envy,
>   murder, debate, deceit, malignity; whisperers,   Backbiters, haters of
>   God, despiteful, proud, boasters, inventors of evil things,
>   disobedient to parents,   Without understanding, covenantbreakers,
>   without natural affection, implacable, unmerciful:

The action of God was not to create them as homosexuals, but to give them over (paradidōmi) to a reprobate mind. In a way, their lives have become living examples of what life without God is like. They are a living warning of the consequence for rejecting even the knowledge of God.

Comment: I have never heard of anyone refer to same-sex attraction as a punishment before. That is very audacious.

Comment: @timf Perhaps you have encountered effeminate boys - I say this with a lot of respect - who are like that from an early age or also why would one discount the testimony of those with the tendency and that of their parents that *they were born that way*?

Comment: @Hello and \@FMS. Comments are not the place to carry on theological discussions or debate issues. They should be reserved for requests for clarification or suggestions on improving the posts they are made under. Please refrain from using them for discussing thological issues.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best Biblical bases is the Law of God itself.  Is God unjust?

But, while some would certainly object, consider,

> Surely I was sinful at birth,
>   sinful from the time my mother
>   conceived me.
>
> Psalm 51:5

The issue is sin, and whether or not someone was born in sin, conceived even in it, is not the issue.

Whether one is born in sin is not the issue of righteousness, being born again is, and the removal of it.

As for same sex attraction, the argument actually fails for the above description.  Generally, sexual attraction is something that develops in puberty.  With those who claim to be "born that way", they actually exhibit SSA often much earlier, indicating something else entirely.  It is not normal, but sometimes is an indicator of abuse or some other issue.

They may have been indeed born and formed in iniquity, but that's just all the more reason for the cross, and getting rid of it.  God did not create them that way, but they are merely receiving the consequences of sin in their souls.

The other corollary is Exodus 34:6-7 where God said He revisits the sins of the Father's to the children to the third and fourth generation.

Again, the issue that one is born in sin can more than account for the subjective testimony that one is born a certain way.

We were all born rebellious and evil, and no believer makes the case that therefore it is "Ok".

Comment: I love this answer!

Comment: cf. [This answer of mine](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/does-god-create-some-people-heterosexual-and-others-homosexual/30991#30991) perhaps it has some material for you to augment the answer?

Answer (score 0):

What is the biblical basis that people who are attracted to the same sex were not created by God that way? Changed to: "Does God create some people homosexual and others heterosexual?"

Here is Biblical basis that applies to this question.

> And God said, *Let us make man in our image*, *after our likeness*: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.

(Man and Woman were made *in God's image*, God is **not** homosexually oriented, -we have nothing to indicate He leans this way- His creation made *'in His own image'* is also not oriented this way, because God isn't, and we have nothing suggesting that they would be; therefore man and woman created in God's image are only oriented toward each other, as per God's design, especially since they reflect Him and He does not indicate any leaning toward homosexual orientation. Adam and Eve reflect God's image in that they are oriented toward each other, male to female and vice-versa, reflecting God in  His choice to represent Himself as male, and to allude to Israel and to the Bride as female counterparts to His maleness. No 'other' category is ever indicated in reference to Him or to mankind who He created. (other categories would be men who, although in male bodies are attracted to other men in male bodies, and same with females attracted to others in female bodies)

> Matthew 19:4
>   "Haven't you read," he replied, "that at the beginning the Creator 'made them *male and female,'* (there is only male or female, no third of fourth category)

Mark 10:6
"But at the beginning of creation God 'made them *male and female.'*

Genesis 1:28
God *blessed them* and said to them, "Be fruitful and increase in number; fill the earth and subdue it. Rule over the fish in the sea and the birds in the sky and over every living creature that moves on the ground."
(male and female-ness receives a Blessing, contrary to Bible warnings from God against 'other' behavior or practice)

Genesis 5:3
When Adam had lived 130 years, he had ***a son in his own likeness***, ***in his own image***; and he named him Seth.

(This verse portrays that God began with a son in his own likeness and image, and then Adam is spoken of next having a son in his own likeness and image. This *image* and *likeness* is God's and since God portrayed Himself in scripture with maleness, counterparting with what He said about Israel's femaleness, and the Bride of Christ's femaleness, we could say that the image and likeness of God is a heterosexual orientation.
(other orientations do not reflect His image or His likeness)

The Bible also clearly states that "Woman was made for the man, not man for the woman" Nowhere does it state that women were made for women or men for men.

---

Part 2 Are homosexuals born that way, and is God punishing them?

Since man and woman were created in the image of God and God paints Himself as heterosexually oriented, as a male countering the femaleness of Israel and of the Bride fo Christ,. I think it is reasonable to assume that they are not born this way, nor intended to be this way from the Lord.

God does not tempt anyone to sin, the Bible says, so God would not create a homosexual and then tell him he cannot act on this drawing ever. That would be cruel and God is love.

When Adam and Eve fell, all of creation fell with them, the whole thing went into 'shock'. Sin affected ALL, the Bible says. Being born after the fall includes all kinds of physical malfunctions, diseases, etc. things that can go wrong with the babies development and body and some are born with diseases and issues stemming back to all of Creation going wrong, when God had to separate Himself because of the fall.

Homosexual tendencies could be inherent in an infant if physical disease could be in the body of an infant. Something's gone wrong and it isn't the infant's fault, nor probably the parents, although some disease comes directly from sin occurrences, ie. Jesus told someone to stop sinning lest a worse disease come upon them.

The fact that there is disease on earth today, comes directly from the fall, no disease was planned by God to be in His creation originally.

---

God has no pleasure in punishing. (Bible says)

God giving people over to their lust, after a time. I don't think this is God punishing people, I believe, after many many times of convicting and chiding and reprimanding someone - if they continue to rebel and go in this direction in spite of warnings and convictions from God, God may cool down the warnings and allow someone to continue in the direction of their choosing.

This would explain giving them over to their lust and removing hindrances to their sin. Perhaps angels do not run interference for this person any longer, nor do they bring messages from God about  what they are doing being wrong.

No messages from God bother their consciences any more, and they believe a lie that what they are doing is ok.

God does not take pleasure in punishing.  He has no pleasure in the destruction of the wicked.

If the person is a son or daughter of God, having received their new birth, God will punish, as a faithful Father, for quite some time, and the person's flesh may be destroyed through hiv aids (destruction of the flesh, Bible quote) so the person's life is cut short and they themselves saved, by repenting before death.

Homosexual orientation can happen through abuse, from absent mothers or fathers in the formative years, from the youth giving in to sin through some appeal, ie. sexual awareness moving accidentally down the same sex road to exploration etc. and this practiced as habit. (then along comes someone who tells the youth if they ever had a same sex encounter it means they are homosexual, when this does not mean that.)

Wrong relationships with the opposite sex can effect a youth and turn them in the opposite direction sexually, ie cold and distant mother or father may set the child up for a lifetime of seeking approval or love from the same sex, to substitute for the mother or fathers love and affection and approval.

---

The Bible says God made woman for man, and when he saw her, man said 'mmmm, very good'.